# Как осуществить смещение при обращении к стороннему api?

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, yandex-places-api

Как осуществить смещение при обращение к API Яндекс карт? Если, например, можно выгрузить максимум 100 данных за раз, то как выгрузить 101?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос: каких данных и какой API? Видимо, имеется в виду один из [HTTP API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapsapi/#httpapi)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для [HTTP Геокодера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/?from=SO) и для [HTTP API Поиска по организациям](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/request-docpage/?from=SO) есть параметр `skip`, который позволяет пропустить нужное количество объектов в ответе.

Обратите внимание, что параметр skip не позволяет увеличить максимальное количество результатов, которые может вернуть сервис. То есть для Геокодера не выйдет получить более 100 результатов, а для Поиска по организациям больше 500.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Почему-то в этом ключе про skip я и не подумал